# Accessing protected using super

Tags: java, protected, super, access-modifiers

I have following code

```
package com.kathy.accessmodifiers2;

public class base extends Object{
protected int a = 10;
}

package com.kathy.accessmodifiers;
import com.kathy.accessmodifiers2.*;

class derived extends base {
public void D() {
    System.out.println("D");
    base b = new base();
    System.out.println(super.a); //line 1
    //System.out.println(b.a); //line 2
    //Only this class can access the proctected member.
    System.out.println(this.a);
    System.out.println(a);
}
}

class derived2 extends derived {
public void D2() {
    System.out.println(a);
}
}

public class Protected {

public static void main(String str[]) {
    new derived2().D();
}
}
```

In line1, i am using `super.a` and the output is 10. In case of line2, the code does not compile because i am trying to access `protected` member of `super` class (different package) from base class (different package). 
Why in case of `super` the `a` is accessible ?

Comment: Your `Derived` class has no visibility modifier and therefore uses package-private. If you declare it `public Derived extends Base`you should be fine.

Comment: @isnot2bad protected members are accessible by subclass which are inherited, not with instance of parent class. and `b` is instance of parent class here.

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar You're right! I didn't notice the commented line 2. I just copied the source and compiled it. As javac did not complain, I assumed everything works. I'll remove my comment!

Comment: @isnot2bad Its ok...you can refer my answer also...!!

Answer (score 2):

That is

`protected` member of a class of one package is accessible in another package if and only if this class is inherited by some other class  in another package.

1   i.e  in above example `base` class is extended by `derived` class in different package  so its(**base** class) protected members are accessible by `super` keyword.

2  but we cannot directly access `base` class' `protected` members by creating its `object` in another package.because they are accessible in same package ***until we not inherit that class in another package***

Answer (score 1):

```
base b = new base();
System.out.println(super.a); //line 1
System.out.println(b.a); //line 2
```

**In line 1 :**
`super.myMethod()` or `super.variable` will call a overridden method or to access overridden properties.
so by line 1, you are accessing the overridden `int a` in child class.

**while in line 2 :**
`int a` has `protected` access modifier in `class B` so you can not access it from different package, and you are trying to access the `int a` by `b` which is instance of `class B` from different package.

Simple is that.

Reference Javadoc :

1. [Using the Keyword super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)
2. [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)